# What do the other farmers symbolize in Animal Farm?

Tags: george-orwell, animal-farm

I remember reading somewhere that Mr. Pilkington, Frederick, and the other farmers in Animal Farm symbolized different countries, but I forgot which country they each symbolized. Is that true, and if it is, can someone remind me which countries the individual farmers symbolized?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [*Animal Farm* is not a work of science fiction or fantasy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6471/is-animal-farm-on-topic)

Comment: Related Meta - [Why has this Animal Farm question been reopened?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10516/why-has-this-animal-farm-question-been-reopened)

Comment: Related policy meta - [Is Animal Farm on-topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6471/is-animal-farm-on-topic) (Hint : no, it's not)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not countries, but people - see http://www.newspeakdictionary.com/go-animal_farm.html. Pilkington stands for rulers of England, Frederick for those of Germany.